# Is it possible to pass a model value between two methods in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I need to pass value from my first controller method to an other,
In my controller:

```
@RequesMap...
public string examplemethod(Model model)
{
    some codes...
    model.addAttribute("a",a);
    return page1;
}
```

So the second method is basicly empty, just returns with a JSP where I want to show the value of the "a" variable.

```
@RequesMap...
public string examplemethod2()
{
   return page2;
}
```

Comment: Controllers are a little different.  You should encapsulate populating that model data into a separate POJO that the two controllers can share.

Comment: But I have one controller, I want to pass from one method to other in the same controller.

Comment: HTTP doesn’t work that way.

Comment: So there is no any options to do it?

Comment: I gave you an option: refactor the common bit into a single method and let both handler methods call it.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem:

model.addAttribute("a",a);

In "a" I stored a string value inside my first method, and I wanted to pass it my other method, but If I declared my "a" string outside the method, I can use its value easily in my other method.